# Order rows with specific parameters

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table filled as follows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3736a/4, what I'm trying to do is the next:

I have n groups of names (in this case 4 group names: CAFE NESCAFE, CAFE LEGAL, CAFE INTERNA, null) from the column nom_agrupacion, and I need to sort them first by nom_agrupacion (name of group) and then by other column which is costo.

The query to do that is this

```
SELECT * FROM bby_venta_co WHERE promocion_id = 100000189
AND ti = 153
AND ffi = 12
AND ci = 1
ORDER BY nom_agrupacion DESC, costo DESC;
```

and get this

```
ID  DTTI    TI     FFI  CI  PROMOCION_ID    CODIGO_BARRAS   COSTO   NOM_AGRUPACION
53  1101    153     12  1   100000189       7501001602727   34.55   CAFE NESCAFE
55  1102    153     12  1   100000189       7501001602727   34.55   CAFE NESCAFE
62  1107    153     12  1   100000189       7501059224841   19.45   CAFE NESCAFE
65  1108    153     12  1   100000189       17501052411115  28.3    CAFE LEGAL
66  1109    153     12  1   100000189       17501052411115  28.3    CAFE LEGAL
67  1110    153     12  1   100000189       7501052411118   24.8    CAFE LEGAL
57  1103    153     12  1   100000189       7501052411118   24.8    CAFE LEGAL
61  1106    153     12  1   100000189       17501052418732  55.6    CAFE INTERNA
52  1100    153     12  1   100000189       27501052418739  32.6    CAFE INTERNA
51  1099    153     12  1   100000189       27501052418739  32.6    CAFE INTERNA
60  1105    153     12  1   100000189       7501052418520   19.35   CAFE INTERNA
59  1104    153     12  1   100000189       7501000112388   12.9    (null)
68  1111    153     12  1   100000189       7501000112388   12.9    (null)
```

But I need to sort the information so I can get this: Bring the first row of every group name(I got 4 becasue null counts as group also) then bring the second row of every group and so on to get something like this

```
ID  DTTI    TI     FFI  CI  PROMOCION_ID    CODIGO_BARRAS   COSTO   NOM_AGRUPACION
53  1101    153     12  1   100000189       7501001602727   34.55   CAFE NESCAFE
66  1109    153     12  1   100000189       17501052411115  28.3    CAFE LEGAL
61  1106    153     12  1   100000189       17501052418732  55.6    CAFE INTERNA
59  1104    153     12  1   100000189       7501000112388   12.9    (null)
55  1102    153     12  1   100000189       7501001602727   34.55   CAFE NESCAFE
65  1108    153     12  1   100000189       17501052411115  28.3    CAFE LEGAL
52  1100    153     12  1   100000189       27501052418739  32.6    CAFE INTERNA
68  1111    153     12  1   100000189       7501000112388   12.9    (null)    
62  1107    153     12  1   100000189       7501059224841   19.45   CAFE NESCAFE
57  1103    153     12  1   100000189       7501052411118   24.8    CAFE LEGAL
51  1099    153     12  1   100000189       27501052418739  32.6    CAFE INTERNA
60  1105    153     12  1   100000189       7501052418520   19.35   CAFE INTERNA
```

Is this even possible in one query?

I have tried to at least bring the first row of every group once but my query isn't working properly:

```
SELECT * FROM bby_venta_co WHERE promocion_id = 100000189
AND ti = 153
AND ffi = 12
AND ci = 1
GROUP BY  costo, nom_agrupacion
ORDER BY nom_agrupacion DESC, costo DESC;
```

I use group by to first bring the single cost and then bring the single nom_agrupacion but it seems it only reads cost, and if I only use group by nom_agrupacion it doesn't bring me the rows of column costo with the highest values.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT b.*,
          @row := (COALESCE(nom_agrupacion, 'NULL') = @nom) * @row + 1 AS 'row',
          @nom := COALESCE(nom_agrupacion, 'NULL')
      FROM bby_venta_co AS b
      JOIN (SELECT @row := 0, @nom := '') AS r
      WHERE promocion_id = 100000189 and ticket_id = 153 and fondo_fijo_id = 12 and caja_id = 1 
      ORDER BY nom_agrupacion DESC, costo_original DESC
  ) AS sub
ORDER BY `row`, nom_agrupacion DESC
```

Ok, explanation of what's going on. first the subquery:

1. We join the table data to to variables which we init with blank values
   `FROM bby_venta_co AS b JOIN (SELECT @row := 0, @nom := '') AS r`
2. Next we set `@nom` to `nom_agrupacion`, however the `(null)`'s would give an issue
   (due to comparison) so we use `COALESCE` to use the *string* NULL if the value is NULL
3. `(COALESCE(nom_agrupacion, 'NULL') = @nom)` will cast false / 0 if `@nom` is not `nom_agrupacion` (of course, we once again have to use `COALESCE` due to the `(null)`'s)
4. So this effectively creates `@row := (0 or 1) * @row + 1`. So we continuously increase by 1, except for the moment `@nom` doesn't equal `nom_agrupacion`, which is when `nom_agrupacion` changes at which point we multi[ply with 0, resetting the counter. So we now effectively have a sub-order counter, counting the price position of the 2nd ORDER, i.e. `costo_original` *within* the first ORDER

Just run the subquery seperately to get a better grip of the above.

1. Finally, we select the whole and order by this `'row'` (grouping by 'price position') and then the `nom_agrupacion`.

Comment: Many many many thanks, Can you please explain the query just to clarify, because I have no idea what you did there.

Comment: Added explanation to post as it was a bit long, hope it helps.